# How can i give SECADM to instance owner in DB2?

Tags: db2, permissions

i'm using db2 9.7 on linux and created a user "db2fee1i" to be a instance owner. I restored a database, but even being SYSADM i only can connect to database. I need to give DATAACCESS to another user, and even doing a query appears...

> The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a
>   valid Command Line Processor command. During SQL processing it
>   returned: SQL0551N "DB2FEE1I" does not have the required authorization
>   or privilege to perform operation "EXECUTE" on object
>   "NULLID.SQLC2H23". SQLSTATE=42501

I tryed everything but nothing solves my problem, now i found "SECADM" that can give me the "privileges to execute" into database, but i dont know how to do it. Someone can help me?!

Answer (score 1):

Under 9.7, whichever ID creates the database is automatically granted `DBADM WITH DATAACCESS WITH ACCESSCTRL` and `SECADM`.

So you should be able to log in to the databases with that ID to perform the grants you need. If this came from another environment, you may have to create the ID locally in order to get into the database. Only an ID with `SECADM` can grant `SECADM` to another ID. And also with 9.7, you cannot `GRANT` to or `REVOKE` from yourself.

Now...as to your problem.....when you do not have `EXECUTE` on a `NULLID` package, then you may either need to perform a `BIND` of the appropriate bind file, or grant `EXECUTE` on that package. If it is a system package that pretty much everyone can use, you can always `GRANT EXECUTE ON PACKAGE NULLID.SQLC2H23 TO PUBLIC`.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I was angry so i dropped the database and restore it again!
When I restored it worked properly again ... :D